# Express - Multiple database connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm developing an application with node.js and in login form I ask user to select the database but I don't know how to set the connection with the selected database.

How can I put several connections in my `config.js`?

And how can I set a connection wit a selected database?

```
var mssql = require("mssql");
 var config =
 {
   user: "user",
   password: "password",
   server: "IP",
   database: "db_name"
 }

 var db = new mssql.Connection(config);

 db.connect(function(err)
 {
     console.log(err);
 });

 module.exports = db;
```

Thank you

Comment: First ask yourself if Express is relevant to this issue.

Comment: Each `option` of the (presumable) `<select>` field in your login form should have a value. The select field should have a name (ie `dbName`). When the form is submitted, read `req.body.dbName`, then handle the database connection. From your question it sounds like it won't always be `mssql`.

Answer (score -1):

To do this, you can just make two database connections

```
var mssql = require("mssql");
var config =
{
  user: "user",
  password: "password",
  server: "IP",
  database: "db_name"
}

var db = new mssql.Connection(config);
var db2 = new mssql.Connection(config);

db.connect(function(err)
{
    console.log(err);
});
db2.connect(function(err)
{
    console.log(err);
});
module.exports = {db: db, db2: db2};
```

If you need a separate config, you can just make two configs. To use the first db, just require("config").db and the second db is at require("config").db2